# jQuery with Random Number following?

Tags: jquery, random, callback

I'm trying to figure out why some `jQuery` scripts I have seen have code like

```
jQuery16404190496341289165_1331138533958({ 

  //code

});
```

What is the purpose of the random number following jQuery ? I've also noticed it particuarly in callback functions as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery will define that function as the callback for JSONP requests.

If you look at the HTTP request, you'll probably see `?callback=jQuery16404190496341289165_1331138533958`.

If you can examine that request's response body, you should see `jQuery16404190496341289165_1331138533958(/* object, etc */)`.

Comment: thanks @alex - are you able to elaborate a little more ? :) You mean per http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/#N1014E